# Docker-Compose Services Not Communicating

Tags: mysql, go, docker-compose

Docker noob alert. Hope this isn't a dumb question but I cannot seem to figure out what is going on. I am trying to create a docker-compose file which creates a mysql db with a mounted volume and a go webserver app that connects to the mysql db.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.2
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: northernairport
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /data:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

My go application can't seem to connect to my mysql db though, I thought the "depends_on" would ensure this was possible.

Error I get:

```
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: You opened port 3306 to the world, not just to your other Docker containers. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: how would I open 3306 just to my web docker container? it is the only thing that needs direct db access

Comment: To open 3306 to just your web app you essentially do nothing - remove the ```ports: 3306:3306``` section from your db service definition. Since the two containers share the same network they already expose ports to one another.

Comment: Right that makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `depends_on` only controls the build and startup order for the services.

Your actual issue is more likely that you are using the wrong address from your web application to your database. I see that you have not defined any networks, so you are using the `default` network created for your application by `docker-compose`. This will publish each service by name on the default network's DNS.

So, your web application should probably be using `db:3306` as the database address, not `localhost:3306` or `127.0.0.1:3306` as indicated in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `ports` part is used to map container ports with host in following format `ports (HOST:CONTAINER)`. Which means that you are trying to access host's machine, configure `web` app to connect to `db:3306` instead.

Comment: I marked the other correct just because it was first but yes you were right as well, gave you an up vote. Thanks!